# How can I add an XML namespace in Scala programmatically?

Tags: xml, scala

```
val sitemapXml = <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"></urlset>
```

How do I programmatically add xmlns:image into it to get

`<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"></urlset>`

I need it conditionally otherwise I would just write it in.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace is located at the `scope` of an `Elem`

```
scala> sitemapXml.scope
res0: scala.xml.NamespaceBinding =  xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
```

This is how you would add a new namespace

```
scala> val newNs = scala.xml.NamespaceBinding("image", "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1", sitemapXml.scope)
newNs: scala.xml.NamespaceBinding =  xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
```

And then modify the XML by using the `copy` constructor:

```
scala> sitemapXml.copy(scope = newNs)
res1: scala.xml.Elem = <urlset xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"></urlset>
```